# Airflow Openshift installation with Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, openshift, airflow, redhat, redhat-containers

I tried to install the Airflow via my own image at a public dockerhub, but it works perfect locally, but when I tried to use it on Openshift. I got this error bellow.

> `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13]
> Permission denied: '/.local' Check the permissions.

My Dockerfile working for on Windows and Ubuntu.

```
# VERSION 2.0.0
# AUTHOR: Bruno
# DESCRIPTION: Basic Airflow container

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
LABEL maintainer="Bruno"


# Never prompt the user for choices on installation/configuration of packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TERM linux

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

# Airflow
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.0.0
ARG AIRFLOW_USER_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}

# Define en_US.
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_CTYPE en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_MESSAGES en_US.UTF-8

# Disable noisy "Handling signal" log messages:
# ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS --log-level WARNING

RUN set -ex \
    && buildDeps=' \
        freetds-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        libsasl2-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        git \
    ' \
    && apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get upgrade -yqq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
        $buildDeps \
        freetds-bin \
        build-essential \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        apt-utils \
        curl \
        rsync \
        netcat \
        locales \
    && sed -i 's/^# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8$/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/g' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    && useradd -ms /bin/bash -d ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME} airflow \
    && pip install -U pip setuptools wheel \
    && pip install pytz \
    && pip install pyOpenSSL \
    && pip install ndg-httpsclient \
    && pip install pyasn1 \
    && pip install apache-airflow[crypto,celery,postgres,kubernetes,hive,jdbc,mysql,ssh${AIRFLOW_DEPS:+,}${AIRFLOW_DEPS}]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} \
    && pip install 'redis==3.2' \
    && if [ -n "${PYTHON_DEPS}" ]; then pip install ${PYTHON_DEPS}; fi \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -yqq $buildDeps \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf \
        /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        /tmp/* \
        /var/tmp/* \
        /usr/share/man \
        /usr/share/doc \
        /usr/share/doc-base

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY airflow.cfg ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}/airflow.cfg

RUN chown -R airflow: ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}

EXPOSE 8080 5555 8793

USER airflow
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["webserver"]
```

Comment: OpenShift assigns a random user UID for the Pod's container, so the modules installed using `--user` will not be accessible by the runtime user. The runtime user does not have a `$HOME`, hence the directory `/.local` will be used if you install more modules at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In this context there is one thing you have to be aware of when working with Openshift. By default Openshift runs containers with arbitrary user ids. Container images that are relying on fixed user ids may fail to start due to permission issues.
Therefore please make sure your container images are built according to the rules described in

[https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/openshift_images/create-images.html#images-create-guide-openshift_create-images](http://In%20this%20context%20there%20is%20one%20thing%20you%20have%20to%20be%20aware%20of%20when%20working%20with%20Openshift.%20By%20default%20Openshift%20runs%20containers%20with%20arbitrary%20user%20ids.%20Container%20images%20that%20are%20relying%20on%20fixed%20user%20ids%20may%20fail%20to%20start%20due%20to%20permission%20issues.%20Therefore%20please%20make%20sure%20your%20container%20images%20are%20built%20according%20to%20the%20rules%20described%20in%20https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/openshift_images/create-images.html#images-create-guide-openshift_create-images.).